# Reusing WebClient object to send another HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, http, vonage

Can anyone explain me, why I can't reuse WebClient object to send another HTTP POST request?

This code **doesn't work**:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string buySmsNumberResult = client.UploadString(ApiBuyUrl, apiBuyParams); //it works fine

//but when I try to send another HTTP POST with the existing WebClient object
string updateSmsNumberResult = client.UploadString(ApiUpdateNumberUrl, apiUpdateParams);
//it throws the exception
```

Exception is:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

But if I recreate WebClient object before the second HTTP POST, it works without any issues.

This **code works**.

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string buySmsNumberResult = client.UploadString(ApiBuyUrl, apiBuyParams); 

//recreating of the WebCLient object
client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string updateSmsNumberResult= client.UploadString(ApiUpdateNumberUrl, apiUpdateParams);
```

The API, which I'm using there - this is [Nexmo API](https://docs.nexmo.com/).

Thanks.

Comment: Does remote server return some cookies on your first request? If so, may be `WebClient` maintains cookie container inside itself and it causes second request to fail.

Comment: Personally I'd always create a new object, because you can never know whats been set on the previous one. There's no harm in issuing a `= new WebClient` - At least there wont be any unknown surprises, like this one.

Comment: I'd love to know why this is happening - could you proxy both requests (using something like Runscope) and send them to me? I'm just Tim at Nexmo.

Comment: https://www.runscope.com/docs/sharing shows you how to share a request with someone

Comment: I ran into the same problem - the `WebClient` clears the Headers collection after each request. So if you re-add the Accept header it should work to reuse the client instance.

Comment: It seems that there is a special case for the Authorization header, which is kept intact for the second request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [PHeiberg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476308/reusing-webclient-object-to-send-another-http-request#comment59806661_30476308) stated, `WebClient` clears the `Headers` after the request is done, so adding them again will make it work.

In answer to [LokiSinclair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476308/reusing-webclient-object-to-send-another-http-request#comment49032409_30476308) comment about the personal preference to create a new object, I must say that it is not a good practice if you are using an inherited `WebClient` that uses Cookies and other relevant functionality that you need to share between requests.